# Can't change Authetication type when setting Data collection

Tags: sql-server, mdw

having problem when setting Data collection set on Management Data Warehouse MSSQL 2014

I succesfuly configured Management Data Warehouse MSSQL 2014, but when trying to Configure data collection, on first windows (Setup Data Collection Sets) I want to select Server [...], dialog Connect to Server appears, but I'm not able for given server (dialogue 'Connect to server') select 'SQL Server Authentication' (the dropdown is grayed / disabled), so I'm not able to connect to server, where had been my MDW configured.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot.